# Ruby: rules for implicit hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, syntax

Why second output shows me only one element of `Array`? Is it still `Array` or `Hash` already?

```
def printArray(arr)
    arr.each { | j |
        k, v = j.first
        printf("%s %s %s \n", k, v, j)
    }
end

print "Array 1\n"
printArray( [
                {kk: { 'k1' => 'v1' }},
                {kk: { 'k2' => 'v2' }},
                {kk: { 'k3' => 'v3' }},
            ])


print "Array 2\n"
printArray( [
                kk: { 'k1' => 'v1' },
                kk: { 'k2' => 'v2' },
                kk: { 'k3' => 'v3' },
            ])

exit

# Output:
#
# Array 1
# kk {"k1"=>"v1"} {:kk=>{"k1"=>"v1"}} 
# kk {"k2"=>"v2"} {:kk=>{"k2"=>"v2"}} 
# kk {"k3"=>"v3"} {:kk=>{"k3"=>"v3"}} 
# Array 2
# kk {"k3"=>"v3"} {:kk=>{"k3"=>"v3"}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby interpreted the second example as an array with a single hash as its element (the curly braces are implied). It is equivalent to this:

```
[{ kk: { 'k1' => 'v1' }, kk: { 'k2' => 'v2' }, kk: { 'k3' => 'v3' }}]
```

Only the last `'kk'` is shown because hashes can't have duplicate keys; only the last one sticks.

If you want an array with multiple hashes as elements, you need to use the syntax like on your first example.

---

More examples on which ruby implies a hash start:

```
# Only argument on method calls
def only_arg(obj)
  puts obj.class
end

only_arg(bar: "baz")  # => Hash

# Which is equivalent to:
only_arg({bar: "baz"}) # => Hash


# Last argument on method calls
def last_arg(ignored, obj)
  puts obj.class
end

last_arg("ignored", bar: "baz") # => Hash

# Which is equivalent to:
last_arg("ignored", { bar: "baz" }) # => Hash


# Last element on an array
def last_on_array(arr)
  puts arr.last.class
end

last_on_array(["something", "something", bar: "baz"]) # => Hash

# Which is equivalent to:
last_on_array(["something", "something", { bar: "baz" }]) # => Hash
```

Comment: Is it because first element in `Array` is `Hash` element? Whenever I write a `Hash` element Ruby starts a `Hash`?

Comment: Not really. Ruby can deduce the curly braces for hashes on most cases. I will give some examples on the answer

Comment: Hmm. I see. In other hand this `['k1'=>'v1','aa','k3'=>'v3']` gives an error : `syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tASSOC` at the middle element..  confusing

Comment: Yes, it only works when the hash is the last element (of the method call or the array). If you need two hashes, or a hash before a non-hash, you need the curlies.

Comment: It seems this works fine as well: ['a1', k1:'v1', k2:'v2']. So if `Hash` elements starts in the middle to the end of `Array` it is automatically 'merged' to `Hash`. Thanks for throwing light on this interesting feature!

Comment: It is really just a single hash; it is equivalent to `['a1', { k1:'v1', k2:'v2' }]`. If you dive into Rails, you'll see this kind of pattern (accepting a hash as the last argument) everywhere. It is pretty convenient

Comment: Aaah. I see you mean full `Hash` at the end not only element at the end. Perfect!