# Creating an array containing a hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, literals

QUESTION EDIT - Breakdown how the 2nd example creates a hash.

I can't figure out why the first example below does not create a hash and the second one does.

```
a: :b
# => SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input
```

vs.

```
[a: :b]
# => [{:a => :b}]
```

Comment: The bracketless hash syntax (what you are trying to use) only works in certain circumstances.

Comment: Because Ruby's syntax sugar for immediate hashes isn't applicable to every possible Ruby construct.

Comment: @DaveNewton would you have reference to the documentation that would show the chain of how this is getting processed? PS. Thanks for the edit

Comment: Not really, but there are more examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19870350/438992) and other places. You could try searching the web for stuff like "Ruby implicit hash" but I'm not sure it's stated explicitly in any official docs. You might also check the Ruby lang specs to examine actual behavior.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks so much, this will take me far!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you just have `a: :b` that is a statement and it is invalid Ruby syntax.

When you have `[a: :b]`, you are actually calling a method. The method you are calling is `[](a: :b)`. When you give `a: :b` as the argument to a method Ruby sees it as a hash and gives the method `{:a => :b}` as it's argument. So the end result is the `[{:a => :b}]` that you are seeing.

Comment: The [](a: :b) method totally makes sense now, after reading the Array documentation I didn't know [a: :b] == [](a: :b), but after your explanation it makes sense.  Now why ruby will see it as a hash is another thing, but you cleared up this method for me.  Thanks

Comment: Excellent! I believe it is also true that `a: :b` or `'c'=>'d'` is interpreted as a hash *only if* it is the argument of a method. (It cannot not, for example, be a receiver.) It true, that would be welcome, as it would tell us exactly where the bracket-less form can and cannot be used.